# I can't understand how ax.set_aspect() works

Tags: python, matplotlib

It has the following parameters:

- aspect : {'auto', 'equal'}
- adjustable : None or {'box', 'datalim'}

But when I use this function I always try every option but still haven't figured out the pattern.

Comment: `ax.set_aspect('equal')`, for example - what are you trying to accomplish with this method?

Comment: I mainly use this to change the axis extents and also the aspect of x-axis compared to y-axis